# How do you cut a string at a certain character, without using split, substring, or index?

Tags: java

for a school assignment, I have to cut the string off at a certain character. It takes an email as input, ex: name@mail.ca, and it has to print everything before the @ sign. We are not allowed to use substring, index or  split. I've attached what i've tried so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getPrefix("name@email.ca");
}


public static String getPrefix(String email) {
    String prefix = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < email.length(); i++) {
        if (email.charAt(i) == '@') {
            break;

        }

        prefix += email.charAt(i);
    }
    return prefix;
}
```

if i set the input as name@email.ca it prints: ame@email.caame@email.caame@email.caame@email.ca

So right now it is only taking away the first character, when instead I need it to take away everything from the @ onwards.

Also,I have to return the value rather than just print it, so how would I do that outside the loop.

Comment: `email.replaceFirst("@.*", "")`

Comment: The question is not really clear. Do you need a function to return a String? If printing the String is good enough, what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: @Gendarme updated the q, sorry about that

Comment: Replace the whole inner loop with `System.out.print(email.charAt(i));`.

Comment: @Gendarme that worked thanks, but I realized that it has to return the prefix rather than just print it, so I changed my method to a String method. Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: Take [Deadpool's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54641409/5221346) and replace `System.out.println(builder)` with `return builder.toString();`.

Comment: @Gendarme the only string methods we can use are: e length(), charAt(), equals(), equalsIgnoreCase(),
toLowerCase(), and toUpperCase().

Comment: In your code shown it is a good start, but in your second loop you only need to print until the character was found, so you need to track the value of `i` at that point, then use that as your upper limit in the 2nd loop.  Alternatively, just `System.out.print` (NOT `println`) until you hit the `@` character, then print out a new line.

Comment: This code doesn't print anything, but if it did it would print `name`, assuming you are printing the result of `getPrefix()`. Cannot reproduce/not a real question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `StringBuilder` to append each char of string before `@`, If you can't use `StringBuilder` you can use `String` but i won't recommended to use string for this

```
 public static String getPrefix(String email) {

       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();    // or String str = "";

       for (int i = 0; i < email.length(); i++) {
            if (email.charAt(i) == '@') {
                break;

            }
            builder.append(email.charAt(i));      //or str+=email.charAt(i);
       }
      return builder.toString();                   //or return str;
   }
```

Comment: the only string methods we can use are: e length(), charAt(), equals(), equalsIgnoreCase(),
toLowerCase(), and toUpperCase(). :(

Comment: updated but i won't recommend using `String` for this

Comment: i did it with string now, but now it doesnt return anything

Comment: can you show the code, you should print it or assign it to a variable @UmarVahidy

Comment: public static String getPrefix(String email) {
  String prefix = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < email.length(); i++) {
   if (email.charAt(i) == '@') {
    break;

   }

   prefix += email.charAt(i);
  }
  return prefix;
 }

Comment: Where are you calling this method? Please update code in post not comment

Comment: im calling this in the main method, and just updated the post thanks

Comment: show the main method and input you are passing @UmarVahidy

Comment: expected this, do like this `String str = getPrefix("name@email.ca");`
`System.out.println(str);` in main method @UmarVahidy